# How to trigger scroll event keeping scrollTop 1px in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop, eventtrigger

I want to trigger a scroll event handler with scrollTop value of 1px. When I do the following:

```
$("#myElement").scrollTop = 1;
$("#myElement").scroll();
```

This doesn't work as it triggers the scroll event handler but with a scrollTop value of 0. Please suggest a way to trigger the scroll event keeping scrollTop 1px.

Answer (score 0):

If `#myElement` is scrollable then you code should be,

```
$("#myElement").scrollTop( 1 );
```

About jQuery [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: Does this work only when #myElement is scrollable?? We cannot give any arbitrary value to scrollTop if the element can't attain it?

Comment: If you want to scroll the page to specific area then use `$(window).scrollTop(VALUE)`. So in your case I think you want to scroll to `#myElement` so the code would be `$(window).scrollTop($("#myElement").scrollTop())`